# How large of a percentage of my training set do I have to use to perform feature selection?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, naive-bayes

I have a data set that has 660,000 samples with 72 features and I'm trying to perform feature selection so that I can train a naive bayes classifier. The problem is that since the data set is so big, I can't process the entire file without my computer freezing up. I originally planed on performing feature ranking with information gain by just taking a subsample of the data. The problem is that each time I run my program, I get a different order for the features.

I'm trying to figure out, how large of a percentage of the training data do i need to get an accurate measure for my information gain?

Comment: Check for collinearity in the features. Look at the covariance structure. I.e. the features might be competing with each other.

Comment: Do you mean check the covariance for each pair combination?

Answer (score 0):

What if you take the average scores(or the average divided by the std) from all runs and then rank the features? Btw I think you should calculate feature importance from the testing set not the training set

Comment: So for example, take a subsample of 5,000 a bunch of times. Let's assume 10,000. Then calculate the information gain for each of these subsamples and divide by the standard deviation? That is similar to bootstrap right?

Comment: Yeah. I think its a valid approach for your case.

Comment: Probably you forgot to write it but just in case: First take the average information gain from the 10000 runs for each feature and then divide each feature by its std across runs